# Linking multiple stylesheets

Tags: css, xhtml

I am using a Dedicated Server.
In the web-hosting side, I have folders arranged like so.

- html

  - forum

    - files
  - images

    - files
  - Equinox

    - index.php
    - header.php
    - footer.php
  - style

    - style.css
  - mc-multiplayer

    - style

      - style.css
    - index.php
    - header.php
    - footer.php

I am trying to get the index.php of mc-multiplayer to link to the css file in mc-multiplayer, but no matter what it keeps going to the style.css file in the html folder.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I would suggest using the following code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
```

Make sure to confirm that everything is cased/spelled correctly and that directories are correct.  As Kevin Boucher suggested, it would help to know the link you're currently using.

Answer (score 0):

from a page within the `mc-multiplayer` subdirectory (as long as a [`<base>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4) isn't overriding the directory context)

this **might work** (no prefix (such as `/` or `../`) before `style` should maintain the current folder context, then `style` subdir then the file):

```
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

this **should definitely work** (`/` to start at the root of the site then into `mc-multiplayer` subdir then `style` subdir to the file):

```
<link href="/mc-multiplayer/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```